# Error serializing value 'System.String[]' of type 'System.String[].'

Tags: c#, asp.net, serialization, encoding

This error appears due to this line of code at the aspx page

```
<div class="full-content-note">
    <%# Item.FullNoteContents %>
</div>
```

because the property FullNoteContents contains some emojis.

I tried to update the code to be like the following but the HTML as it is (the tags appeared).

```
<div class="full-content-note">
    <%# Server.HtmlEncode(Item.FullNoteContents) %>
</div>
```

Here is the full exception log

> System.ArgumentException: Error serializing value 'System.String[]' of type 'System.String[].' ---> System.Text.EncoderFallbackException: Unable to translate Unicode character \uDFFC at index 847 to specified code page.
>      at System.Text.EncoderExceptionFallbackBuffer.Fallback(Char charUnknown, Int32 index)
>      at System.Text.EncoderFallbackBuffer.InternalFallback(Char ch, Char*& chars)
>      at System.Text.UTF8Encoding.GetByteCount(Char* chars, Int32 count, EncoderNLS baseEncoder)
>      at System.Text.UTF8Encoding.GetByteCount(String chars)
>      at System.IO.BinaryWriter.Write(String value)
>      at System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.SerializeValue(SerializerBinaryWriter writer, Object value)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.SerializeValue(SerializerBinaryWriter writer, Object value)
>      at System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.Serialize(Object stateGraph, Purpose purpose)
>      at System.Web.UI.Util.SerializeWithAssert(IStateFormatter2 formatter, Object stateGraph, Purpose purpose)
>      at System.Web.UI.HiddenFieldPageStatePersister.Save()
>      at Revindex.Business.Revindex.Revindex.Optimizer.OptimizerPageStatePersister.Save()
>      at System.Web.UI.Page.SaveAllState()
>      at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Comment: Can you try to use this: `Server.HtmlEncode(Item.FullNoteContents.Text.Replace("U+", "0x").ToLower())`?

Comment: I tried it and the same issue appeared; the HTML tags are displayed as text.